# QSerialPort starts communication after to some data were transmitted

Tags: qt, serial-port, buffer, serial-communication

I am trying to send and receive some serial data with QSerialPort but it take a little time. So I open a Serial Terminal. (Terminal v1.93b - 20141030B) Then with it terminal I read and send data and when I tried again with my application, it starts correctly.

So why it happens after do I open the serial terminal and some data are sended the QSerialPort works fine. It looks like if I need to reset or refresh the serial buffer on my port.

Comment: What do you have your serial port hooked up to? You are opening a some COM port with the QSerialPort class, and when you open the other side of that connection with a Terminal you can get data back and forth. So to me this says that whatever you are trying to connect to is not responding, or not configured properly. Most times this is due to an incorrect baud rate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the function **clear()** after opening a serial port, or to call the function **flush()** after each sending data.

```
bool QSerialPort::clear(Directions directions = AllDirections)
bool QSerialPort::flush()
```